# Post запрос с передачей файла и ID (Axios)

Tags: javascript, c#, axios, asp.net-web-api

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с непонятками при создании запроса.

Имеется Web Api C#
И Фронт на VUE JS с Axios

У меня уже есть метод контроллера на шарпе для пост запроса, который принимает файл.

```
      [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<List<FileImportResult>> UploadArchive(IFormFile file CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(new FileUploadCommand { Archive = file }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Но мне не удается его дорботать, чтобы он принимал файл и ID поьзователя
Пробовал делать так

```
      [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<List<FileImportResult>> UploadArchive(IFormFile file,Guid UserId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(new FileUploadCommand { Archive = file, UserId = UserId }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

И вот так

```
      [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<List<FileImportResult>> UploadArchive(FileUploadCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
    }
```

где FileUploadCommand это

```
    public class FileUploadCommand : IRequest<List<FileImportResult>>
{
    [Required]
    public IFormFile Archive { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Но все тщетно. в контроллер приезжает null

И еще кое что.
на фронте, когда отправляю только data (только файл)
В нетворк в пост запросе можно посмотреть , что отправлен файл

НО если я отправляю и файл и ID
то в нетворк в запросе у меня объект
где файл как пустой объект , а с ID все норм

```
{
Archive: {}
UserID: "******"
}
```

Вот в таком варианте работает. Где data - это файл.

```
  public uploadArchive (data: any) {
return Api.post('Import/UploadArchive', data)
  .then((r) => {
    return r.data
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error', error)
    return null
  })
```

}

А вот в таков варинте уже нет... отправляется JSON пример крирого я указал выше с пустым Archive

```
    public uploadArchive (data: any, id: any) {
    return Api.post('Import/UploadArchive', {Archive: data, UserId: id})
      .then((r) => {
        return r.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error)
        return null
      })
  }
```

Comment: А если ракеты поснифать, то какой формат данных? multipart/form-data? Кстати, можете схитрить и зашить id пользователя в имя файла.

Comment: @aepot не совсем понял про сниф ракет. Можно пояснение ? ) Если вы про content-type в запросе, то когда отправляю чисто файл контент тайп : Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed.  Идея и ID  имени файла не плоха, но оргинальнеоимя файла мне тоже нужно :)

Comment: @aepot попробовал отправить запрос без ID . Просто обернуть только data в объект.
И опять JSON с тустым обхектом { Archive: {} }

Comment: application/x-zip-compressed - это поток данных, вы не можете туда больше ничего засунуть, потому что это тупо файл. Для передачи смешанных данных нужен другой тип контента на базе multipart/form-data или multipart/mixed, вот и ищите в эту сторону, как отправить и принять multiart